# NotAMockException / How to stub a value in parameterized test in Kotlin?

Tags: junit, kotlin, mockito, robolectric, parameterized-tests

For the following Kotlin class:

```
class ProductLogic(

        private val product: Product?

) {

    fun shouldShow(): Boolean {
        if (product == null) {
            return false
        }
        val version = product.version!!
        if (!Utils.isAtLeastVersionX(version.major, version.minor)) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

I am trying to write a parameterized test in Kotlin:

```
@RunWith(ParameterizedRobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig::class, sdk = [19], packageName = "com.example")
class ProductLogicTest(

        private val product: Product?,
        private val shouldShow: Boolean

) {

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        // doReturn(VERSION).`when`(product).version // (2) Raises a NotAMockException
    }

    @Test
    fun shouldShow() {
        assertThat(ProductLogic(product).shouldShow(), `is`(shouldShow))
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @Parameters(name = "{index}: {0} => {1}")
        fun data(): Collection<Array<Any?>> {
            val productMock = mock<Product>(Product::class.java)
            doReturn(VERSION).`when`(productMock).version // (1) Is not applied
            return asList(
                       arrayOf(productMock, false),
                       // ...
            )
        }

}
```

I want to parameterize the value of the `Product#version` property. When I (1) modify its value in the `data()` function it is not applied when running test. When I (2) try to modify its value in `@Before` a `NotAMockException` is raised:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
Example of correct stubbing:
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
```

*Please note that the example is simplified - the real `ProductLogic` class consists of more parameters which rectify to using a parameterized test.*

Answer (score 5):

Robolectric and Mockito versions:

```
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.1'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4'
```

Also, to mock final classes, I created file `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` with content:

```
mock-maker-inline
```

Classes to test:

```
class ProductLogic(private val product: Product?) {
    fun shouldShow(): Boolean {
        if (product == null) {
            return false
        }
        val version = product.version
        return !isAtLeastVersionX(version.minor, version.major)
    }

    private fun isAtLeastVersionX(minor: Int, major: Int): Boolean {
        val v = 5
        return v in minor..major
    }
}

class Product(val version: Version)

class Version(val minor: Int, val major: Int)
```

Next test code works for me and test is passed:

```
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.`is`
import org.junit.Assert.assertThat
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn
import org.mockito.Mockito.mock
import org.robolectric.ParameterizedRobolectricTestRunner
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config
import java.util.Arrays.asList

@RunWith(ParameterizedRobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [19], packageName = "com.example")
class ProductLogicTest(private val product: Product,
                       private val shouldShow: Boolean) {

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        //doReturn(VERSION).`when`(product).version // if uncomment works fine
    }

    @Test
    fun shouldShow() {
        assertThat(ProductLogic(product).shouldShow(), `is`(shouldShow))
    }


    companion object {
        private val VERSION = Version(1, 5)

        @JvmStatic
        @ParameterizedRobolectricTestRunner.Parameters(name = "{index}: {0} => {1}")
        fun data(): Collection<Array<Any?>> {
            val productMock = mock(Product::class.java)
            doReturn(VERSION).`when`(productMock).version // Works fine
            return asList(
                    arrayOf(productMock, false)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your example. It works in the current state. - The scenario I have is that I would like to test different values for `VERSION`. Therefore, it cannot be assigned within the `companion object` as `val`. I rather want to run each test instance with a different value of `VERSION`. I tried that in the `@Before` method.

Comment: I tested method with `@Before` annotation and it works as well. You can create different local instances of `Version` and test against them.

Comment: I would like to define the different `VERSION` values here: `arrayOf(product = productMock, version = 1, shouldShow = false), arrayOf(product = productMock, version = 2, shouldShow = false), ...`

Comment: I think there shouldn't be a problem. You can create additional constructor param in `ProductLogicTest ` and use it: `class ProductLogicTest(private val product: Product,
                       private val version: Int,
                       private val shouldShow: Boolean)`

Comment: Please note that `product` is nullable. Therefore, the `@Before doReturn...` statement can only run if `product != null` which is fine. However, the test execution still fails with an `NotAMockException` as mentioned in my question.

Comment: I don't encounter this error even after I change constructor parameter to `private val product: Product?` and add nullability validation in `@Before` method.